# Manipulating values of datapoints within ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have applied a smoothing filter to some data using the code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = price), data = df1) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth()
```

And I've done this for a few datasets. What I want to do now is standarize the smoothed line which shows the average prices so that the y axis value for all charts begins at 100. To do this I would ideally divide all data points of the smoothed line by the value of the first data point and multiply by 100. i.e. (y/y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLbVd.jpg)*100) This will make it easier to compare the smoothed line and average prices between datasets. I've tried this using a mutate function but it doesn't seem to work within ggplot2 after I've plotted the graph (but I need to plot the graph first in order to know the first y value). I'm not sure what other functions I can try or how to approach it. Any help would be appreciated!

I've created a sample dataframe for you to use and inserted a picture of the sample smoothing graph:

```
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2015/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
price <- round(runif(100,1,100), 2)
df1 <- data.frame(date, price)
```

[image: Smoothing Graph]

Comment: Hi Jay, if you could supply an example of a dataset and show some figures of what you've been doing so far. It's difficult to help you just from this question.

Comment: Updated and saved a picture of the smoothing graph. So I'd want all values of the blue line to be divided by 53.5 and multiplied by 100. (I am just eyeballing this figure but is there a way to extract the exact value of the first value of the smoothed line?) @Peter H

Comment: Ahh, much clearer now. If you're using the defaults of geom_smooth(), the underlying modelling is `loess()`. You could do that modelling prior to plotting and then extract the initial average from the model to do the normalisation.

Comment: My actual dataset is much larger and has many more observations so it uses the GAM method. Would I still be able to do this?

Comment: I can't see why that wouldn't be the case. An alternative and simpler approach would be to normalise your data points to the average of the first couple of observations.

Answer (score 2):

One can code this directly into `aes`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = date, y = price/price[which.min(date)]*100)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() + 
  ylab('price (% relative to first record)')
```

[image]

Comment: I think this function takes the first price in the data set and not the average price as shown on the graph, so then the standardized graph won't begin at 100?